# Is it possible to configure my Airflow environment (2.4.3) to auto restart the scheduler after adding a plugin?

Tags: environment-variables, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have an Airflow environment (V2.4.3) that gets the following error after I add a plugin and DAGs that reference the plugin

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/hello_dag.py", line 6, in <module>
    from operators.hello_operator import HelloOperator
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'operators'
```

The solution for this is to manually restart the scheduler

However, I am wondering if there exists some configuration via environment variables that I can use to configure the airflow environment to automatically restart the scheduler without requiring me to do it manually?

I looked through the documentation but did not find anything so I am asking here in case I missed something.

If not possible, do let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set [lazy_load_plugins](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#lazy-load-plugins) to `False` to load the plugins for each process instead of restarting the scheduler, but the restart is more recommended.

Restarting the scheduler and/or the other components is not supported by Airflow and it should not be supported where this is a CD task depends on how do you deploy Airflow.

If you are deploying it on K8S, you can restart the deployment using `kubectl rollout restart deployment/<name>`, and if you are using docker or you run it directly on your host machine, you can use [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to run `docker restart <container name>` for docker, and for host:

```bash
ps aux | grep "airflow scheduler" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill && airflow scheduler <pass your args>
```